# С# Добавление символа перед каждым символом

Tags: c#, функции

Ребята,помогите в C# сделать добавление символа перед каждым символом.
Пример : "tour"-Нам даётся вот такое слово,и мы должны его переделать как бы.
Ответ : ".t.o.u.r."-И что бы перед и после каждым символом стояла точка.
Как сделать? C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой пример консольного приложения. Статический метод `AddPresymbols` принимает два агрумента - исходное слово в виде строки и один символ, который будет добавлен перед каждым сомволом исходного слова, а возвращает результат - модифицированную строку.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        public static String AddPresymbols(String word, Char presymbol)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            word.ToList().ForEach(letter => result.Append($"{presymbol}{letter}"));

            result.Append($"{presymbol}");

            return result.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var word = "tour";
            var modifiedWord = AddPresymbols(word, '.');
            Console.WriteLine(modifiedWord);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил правку, чтобы в конце строки тоже добавлялся требуемый символ.

Comment: Спасибо.Я подробно щас посмотрю твой код.

Comment: А почему последний символ точка, а не presymbol?

Comment: @vp_arth, исправил

Answer (score 6):

Алгоритм решения прост: создать новую строку и добавлять в нее попеременно символ разделителя либо символ из исходной строки.

Для реализации можно воспользоваться тем, что строка реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable<char>`, а это значит, что можно воспользоваться [функцией Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548744(v=vs.110).aspx)

Данная функция позволяет проходить по коллекции и накапливать результат прохода в аккумуляторе.

```
var result = word.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(word.Length * 2 + 1), // Создаем пустой StringBuilder
    (sb, c) => sb.Append($".{c}"), // на каждой итерации добавляем в StringBuilder пару символов: точки и текущего символа строки
    sb => sb.Append(".").ToString()) // Добавляем заключительную точку и возвращаем результирующую строку
```

Альтернативным вариантом может быть следующий:

```
var result = word.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(".", word.Length * 2 + 1), // создаем StringBuilder, в котором уже есть символ точки
    (sb, c) => sb.Append($"{c}."), // на каждой итерации добавляем в StringBuilder пару символов: точки и текущего символа строки
    sb => sb.ToString()); // возвращаем результирующую строку
```

---

Как подсказывают в комментариях: при больших строках вместо интерполированных строк лучше использовать последовательные вызовы Append, т.е.

```
(sb, c) => Append(".").sb.Append(c)
```

либо

```
(sb, c) => sb.Append(c).Append(".")
```

в зависимости от выбранного ранее варианта

---

Кроме *Aggregate* можно воспользоваться [функцией Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx), но так как данная функция вставит разделители только внутри строки - нужно будет добавить точки спереди и сзади, например так:

```
var result = $".{string.Join<char>(".", word)}."
```

В данном случае нужно явно указать, что у коллекции тип char, в противном случае будет использована перегрузка для string, и точки никуда не будут вставлены.

Либо можно вызвать `AsEnumerable`

```
var result = $".{string.Join(".", word.AsEnumerable())}."
```

В этом случае можно не указывать тип `char`, так как мы явно передаем `IEnumerable<char>` и работает автоматическое выведение типов.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что на Append с интерполяцией, расход памяти удвоится, тупо за счет боксинга char (интерполяция его использует, проверял). Пофиксить можно просто двумя последовательными Append в лямбде, вместо одного, например так `word.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(word.Length * 2 + 1),(sb, c) => sb.Append(".").Append(c),sb => sb.Append(".").ToString())`

Comment: проверил, так и есть, последовательный Append лучше

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string f = SplitStringByDot(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(f);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string SplitStringByDot(string s)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? "WRONG!" : string.Format(".{0}.", string.Join(".", s.ToCharArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: `ToCharArray` можно не делать, чтобы не создавать лишний массив

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, обратил внимание на ваш ответ